# Make git pull --recurse-submodules update submodule to latest commit on submodule branch

Tags: git, git-submodules

I want `git pull --recurse-submodules` to update all submodules to the latest commit on their branch.

`.gitmodules`:

```
[submodule "roles-shared"]
    path = roles-shared
    url = ../../project/roles-shared.git
    branch=master
```

I update `master` branch in roles-shared repository, adding 1 new commit.

I do `git pull --recurse-submodules` in main repository:

```
Fetching submodule roles-shared
From gitlab:project/roles-shared
   83de1f4..f0688dd  master     -> origin/master
Already up to date.
```

Submodule got all new commits, but it not updated, it is 1 commit behind master:

```
# submodule foreach git status

Entering 'roles-shared'
On branch master
Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by 1 commit, and can be fast-forwarded.
  (use "git pull" to update your local branch)
```

Is there any way to make `git pull` automatically update submodules to their latest commits?

Answer (score 3):

git pull && git submodule foreach git pull origin master

Comment: That should work. I hoped for some option in git config or command line switch for git pull, so that workflow doesn't change a bit from having submodules.